# ASP.NET Site.css doesn't change

Tags: asp.net, css

I opened a new ASP.NET MVC project and ran it. Afterwards, I changed some lines in Site.css. However, when I run the project again and located the element in browser, I realized that style information is the same before I changed it. Stopped and re-run, but no luck at that too.

Than I opened a new project and made my changes before running the project and it worked. Now I need another change in Site.css, but i can't make it changed either. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The css is probably cached. You need to refresh the browser. Ctrl+ F5

Answer (score 2):

Update: To add to **@cocre8or**'s answer: On your project you seem to be caching. To **invalidate** the cache you might have a configuration value. Just change the value to get the latest CSS on the site.